# Error on running nfs

Tags: gaming, windows-error-reporting

I've installed NFS Undercover a few months ago but now when i wanna open it it got me the following error.

```
nfs.exe has encountered a problem and needs to be closed
```

Comment: Similar issue>>>>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzEI0f3M5tA

Comment: That error was caused by one of the patches changing the memory handles and only impacts systems with lower-end video cards in them. One way to fix it is to lower the rez settings for the game. from: https://www.supercheats.com/xbox360/questions/needforspeedprostreet/189375/nfs-exe-has-encountered-a-prob.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
I installed the latest graphics card driver 
And the problem solved.